# wp_redirect function not working properly in wordpress 4.5

Tags: wordpress

wordpress 4.5 version redirect not working

```
 <?php  
    if($_POST['submit_form']){
    wp_redirect(get_permalink(14));
    exit;
    }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit"/>

    </form>
```

Comment: Not working properly ? What does it mean ? What is not working ? Please explain your question in detail.

Comment: Are you sure get_permalink(14) returns a link?

Comment: i want to redirect to another page when form is submit but wp_redirect(get_permalink(14)); not working

Comment: yes
echo get_permalink(14); this is return url

Comment: Did you make wp_redirect(get_permalink(14)); this code just before get_header()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use header after wp_redirecr

```
<?php  
    if($_POST['submit_form']){
    wp_redirect(get_permalink(14));
    exit;
    }
    get_header();
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit"/>

    </form>
```